# How to prevent mono-repo services from importing from each other?

Tags: node.js, monorepo

**Short:** In a mono-repo, how can I allow services to import from common code folder, but not from each other?

### Details

**Current state:** Our project has ~10 micro-services, each hosted in its own repo. We also have a Common repo hosting common code, also in its own repo. We consume the Common repo via npm packages. The major problem with this is that refactoring across common code is hard.

**Desired state:**

1. We have a single repo, each micro-service hosted in its own folder
2. Common also has its own folder
3. Services can import code from common
4. Services can't import code from other services <<< Question: How to enforce that? Any tool/package?

**Example:**

```
+--common
+--service1
+--service2   <-- can import '../common/mycommonCodefile', can't import '../service1/myService1CodeFile'
```

**Note:** Seems that [lerna](https://www.google.com/search?q=Lerna) is used to manage multi-package repos. However, its goal seems to be publishing multiple packages to npm, rather than deployable services.

Comment: In the StackOverflow newsletter, I have found [this](https://monorepo.tools/). It seems very well done, you might be interested in [this paragraph](https://monorepo.tools/#explicit-project-constrains) specifically.

Comment: @MarcoLuzzara: Wow, that's exactly what I need! I have a lot of reading and experimenting to do now...